# SVG Zoom to Component

Tags: html, svg, web, zooming

I'm trying to implement a zoom to component option where the user presses the 'e' key and it zooms right onto the component. I only want there to be one zoom level for this, since I am doing a zoom slider for when the user wants to zoom the entire svg at an incremental pace.

Here are some screenshots of examples
http://i274.photobucket.com/albums/jj265/Erebel55/before_zoom.png
http://i274.photobucket.com/albums/jj265/Erebel55/after_zoom.png

http://i274.photobucket.com/albums/jj265/Erebel55/before_zoom2.png
http://i274.photobucket.com/albums/jj265/Erebel55/after_zoom2.png

For each of the above examples, I'm selecting the component with the text "testing" and zooming in on it.

Here is the jsfiddle of what I have so far
http://jsfiddle.net/6Jg2A/3/

By component, I mean a  within the svg. Which contains an image, text, and rect.

It isn't fully working yet. For example, if you select the pink component and press e to zoom you can see that it doesn't really zoom to it correctly.

I think that I need to translate the components as well, I'm just trying to wrap my head around how to do that.

Wondering if anyone could help. Thanks.

Edit: Also, the zoom factor should be dynamic based on component size I think. In other words, when zooming in on a component the end result should be a zoomed component that isn't dependent on the actual size of itself. (I hope this makes sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to zoom the entire svg canvas, not each element separately. You'll also want to grab the transform from the element you're zooming to and adjust the `translate` property of the canvas as well.

I've updated your JSFiddle to show a quick and dirty alternative that works: http://jsfiddle.net/6Jg2A/5/

Comment: Thank you so much for these tips! This looks very good. If I wanted to increase the scaling factor to say 4, I'm assuming I should also change the translate factor.

Also...say we have 2 components. Component A is larger than Component B. However, if I do two separate zooms to A and B, they should look the same size (after the zoom) and then when I zoom back out they should go back to the way they were before (different sizes). Therefore, I think I need to do some calculations based on component size for the zoom factor or something like that. Let me know if that made any sense.

Comment: I will edit original question to include this, sorry for long read.